# Python dynamical methods visible by mypy

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

Suppose you have a class A and it has some member variables like

```
class A:
    member1: type1
    member2: type2
```

You want to create a magic_decorator decorator for the class such
that for each member variable, it creates a function:

```
def set_member1(self, value: type1) -> 'A': 
     self.member1 = value
     return self
```

so:

```
@magic_decorator
class A:
    member1: type1
    member2: type2
```

adds the functions set_member1 and set_member2, this is not too hard. But the catch is you want mypy, flake8, pylint etc to see the functions set_member1, set_member2. Is creating the magic_decorator possible without errors in mypy, flake8, pylint and without ignoring everything related to this class? How would you do this in an Pythonic manner? Would you ignore this pattern overall and just add manually the methods?

Comment: You can do this; `dataclasses.dataclass` does, for example. It is a lot of work, though.

Comment: Thanks, I actually thought of this but was wondering if there is a simpler way, maybe just modify the dataclasses.dataclass.  Or if this is pythonic at all?